# d3: flatten nested data?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

How do I flatten a table based on a series of nested values, using D3?

For the following `cars.json`, I wish to use D3 to flatten the hierarchy, providing a new row for each model `year` of each `model`.  So there should be a total of nine line items, three for each make and model.

I'm sure I'm approaching this wrong, but I'm a bit new at D3, and I don't know how to think about it.  I've seen other questions using `d3.nest`, but as I'm not trying to group anything, it doesn't seem applicable.  Thanks!

**`cars.json`**

```
[
  {
    "make": "Ford",
    "model": "Escape",
    "years": [
      {
        "year": 2013,
        "price": 16525
      },
      {
        "year": 2014
      },
      {
        "year": 2015
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "make": "Kia",
    "model": "Sportage",
    "years": [
      {
        "year": 2012
      },
      {
        "year": 2013,
        "price": 16225
      },
      {
        "year": 2014
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "make": "Honda",
    "model": "CR-V",
    "years": [
      {
        "year": 2008
      },
      {
        "year": 2009
      },
      {
        "year": 2010,
        "price": 12875
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**desired output**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Ford</td><td>Escape</td><td>2013</td><td>16525</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ford</td><td>Escape</td><td>2014</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ford</td><td>Escape</td><td>2015</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kia</td><td>Sportage</td><td>2012</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kia</td><td>Sportage</td><td>2013</td><td>16225</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kia</td><td>Sportage</td><td>2014</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Honda</td><td>CR-V</td><td>2008</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Honda</td><td>CR-V</td><td>2009</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Honda</td><td>CR-V</td><td>2010</td><td>12875</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**current attempt**

```
<table id="cars_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

<script>
(function(){
    d3.json('/static/cars.json', function(error, cars) {

        var tbody = d3.select('tbody')
        rows = tbody.selectAll('tr').data(cars).enter().append('tr')

        rows.append('td').html(function(d) {
            return d.make
        })

        rows.append('td').html(function(d) {
            return d.model
        })

        var years = rows.append('td').html(function(d) {
            return d.years
            // don't want this nested; probably should be peeled out into another `selectAll`, but I don't know where?
        })
    })
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to flatten the data before you render it, so that there is one datum per row (and since the rows are not nested the data shouldn't be nested). That way the table-rendering code you showed should just work.

Ideally, you'd transfer the data flat already. CSV lends itself well to transferring flat data, which is often how it comes out of relational databases. In your case the columns would be "make", "model", "year" and "price", where each make/model appears 3 times — once per year.

If you can't modify the data then flatten it in JS as soon as it's loaded. I'm nearly sure that there isn't a d3 utility for this (`d3.nest()` does the opposite of what you're asking to do), but it's simple enough to do this with a loop:

```
var flatCars = []
cars.forEach(function(car) {
  car.years.forEach(function(carYear) {
    flatCars.push({
      make: car.make,
      model: car.model,
      year: carYear.year,
      price: carYear.price
    });
  });
});
```

or

```
var flatCars = cars.reduce(memo, car) {
  return memo.concat(
    car.years.map(function(carYear) {
      return {
        make: car.make,
        model: car.model,
        year: carYear.year,
        price: carYear.price
      }
    });
  );
}, [])
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense; thanks very much.  If you have a second, can you explain `reduce` and why you might use it here over `forEach`?

Comment: I included the `.reduce()` example mainly for fanciness :) It's hard to glean how it works just by looking at the code that uses it, but should become clear enough if you read the [description of how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: The advantages are marginal in this case, but still: with reduce there's no need for the inner functions to refer to a variable defined outside those functions (`flatCars.push` from the first example). It means that you could write `flatCars = cars.reduce(flattenCar)` where `flattenCar` is defined elsewhere. There's probably some performance boost to that (negligible here). It's also achieving the result in 1 instead of 2 lines, which arguably makes more readable code. I.e. a developer might be puzzled by what `var flatCars = []` is for — until they read the next block of code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to flatten your data before passing it to D3's `data()` method. D3 should be responsible only for transforming data structure into DOM tree. In other words: use nested data structure if you wish a nested DOM structure.

So, flatten data like this (using lodash here):

```
data = _.flatten(data.map(function (model) {
    return model.years.map(function (year) {
        return _.assign(year, _.pick(model, 'make', 'model'));
    });
}));
```

and then pass it to `data()` method. Working codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grPzPJ?editors=1111